Pixel Fold emulator oreintation
I have an activity which I declared to be in portrait mode in the AndroidManifest.xml, using activity's property: android:screenOrientation="portrait" This works fine on real and emulated devices, but when I try the Pixel Fold emulator it seems to ignore the directive, and when I rotate the emulator, the activity becomes landscape inspite of the screenOrientation property being set to portrait.
Does anyone know if it's a but in the Pixel Fold emulator, or does the real device behave in the same way, and if so, how the orientation can be restricted for a foldable device?

Can you include an image of what you're seeing? There are quite a few device compatibility mode changes that force your app to support all orientations (something you should have been doing all along).

@ianhanniballake I'm just using the emulator control arrows to rotate it when unfolded, and I see the activity changes its orientation, although it shouldn't
